# passing env var from docker run cmd inside jenkinsfile to dockerfie

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

Iam trying to pass a variable from jenkinsfile to a dockerfile. So i run a docker run command inside the jenkinsfile :

```
 steps {
          checkout scm
          sh '''
          echo ${GIT_BRANCH}
          mkdir -p `pwd`/build_target
          docker build -t android_build -f docker/Dockerfile.android .
          docker run --env GIT_BRANCH=${GIT_BRANCH} android_build
          ls -la `pwd`/build_target/*
       '''
```

And try to use the env variable inside the dockerfile:

```
 FROM openjdk:8u212-jdk

 USER root
 ENV GIT_BRANCH $GIT_BRANCH
 RUN echo ${GIT_BRANCH}
 RUN if [ "GIT_BRANCH" = "develop" ] ; then echo 'develop' ; else if  [ "GIT_BRANCH" = "master" ] ; then echo 'aster' ; fi
```

But unfortunately it doesn't  work and make the pipeline crashes as it can't get the env var. 
What is wrong with my code ???

Comment: Your `docker run ...` command is missing the name of the image (`android_build`)

Comment: The Dockerfile gets read during the `docker build` line; it has no way of reading environment variables from the future.

Comment: @DazWilkin just a bad copy paste of my code, i edited the code

Comment: @DavidMaze sorry but i don't understand what you said

Comment: Delete the last two lines of the script step and you’ll get the exact same error; it’s never reaching the `docker run` line.

Comment: @DavidMaze i think you are mistaken, it is possible to pass environment variables at runtime

Comment: The Dockerfile _isn’t_ runtime, though, it’s before that.  Nothing you pass in the `docker run` command is visible in the Dockerfile because the Dockerfile happens first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended by fixing the variable at build time with "--build-arg" flag, then i was able to use it inside the dockerfile. Hope it helps someone someday